# Django get unique hours in a datetime field

Tags: django

Is there a method that I am not finding for getting the distinct hours in a DateTimeField? I essentially want the exact same thing that .dates() provides but for hours.

I should clarify that I am talking about a QuerySet method. The dates() method I am talking about is here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#dates-field-kind-order-asc

If not, is there a recommended known solution?

Thanks.

Adding for clarification:
I have a model called Event with a DateTimeField called start_date. We need to know which hours of a particular day have an event.
Let's say that we narrow it down to a particular month:

```
objects = Event.objects.filter(start_date__year=2010, start_date__month=2)
```

Now the dates functions could give me a a list of all the days that have an event:

```
distinct_days = objects.dates('start_date', 'day')
```

What I would like is the narrow it down to a particular day, and then get a distinct list of the hours in the day that have an event.

```
objects = Event.objects.filter(start_date__year=2010, start_date__month=2, start_date__day=3)
distinct_hours = objects.times('start_date', 'hour') # This command doesn't exist and am wondering how to do this
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can describe/show which actual query you want to do. Maybe this can be done without `dates()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a good way to do this at present, the best way is to use some raw SQL in conjunction with the extra() method and then call distinct().

Comment: I've tried adding the following and I can't get a distinct list from it: .extra(select={'hours': 'DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%%H")'})

Comment: You'd need to do .extra(stuff).values_list("hours", flat=True).distinct()

Comment: Here is the end queryset (objects is already filtered down to a specific day):

objects.extra(select={'hours': 'DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%%H")'}).values_list("hours", flat=True).distinct().order_by('hours')

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get the hours from a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object? Which `.dates()` do you mean?

```
hour = instance.yourDateTimeField.hour
```

Comment: +1, though do you mean datetime.datetime.hour (without the 's')? I second the question about `dates()`.

Comment: @Jarret Hardie: Oh your are right about the 's', thank you :)

Comment: I am talking about this:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#dates-field-kind-order-asc

Answer (score 1):

I have created this code in order to manually do it.

```
hours = []
for h in objects.values('start_date'):
    hours.append(h['start_date'].hour)
tempdict = {}
for x in hours:
    tempdict[x] = x
hours = tempdict.values()
hours.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: hours might be stored in separate field, with `unique=True`.